# How do you get a method to be called anytime a DBGrid is displayed?

Tags: delphi, autosize, dbgrid

TMS's DBStringGrid component has a built in method which auto sizes row heights. I understand the property settings required for the method to work, and when called it works well.

I would like my grid's rows autosized anytime the grid is displayed, and I can't figure out where to place the method call. I thought the component's OnCustomCellDraw event would be the proper choice, but that just causes the flickering and memory usage associated with an endless loop (even when grid.doubleBuffering is set to true).

Where would you suggest I place the call to AutoSizeRows if I would like it to be called anytime the grid is being displayed?

UPDATE: Ken's answer is good but I'm also finding placing the call in the DataSource's OnDataChange event, whenever the DB kicks into Edit mode, may be as good for my purposes.

Comment: The flickering in `OnCustomCellDraw` is caused because this event is being fired whenever the cell needs to be drawn. So it's not the right place.

Comment: In the containing form's OnShow event might be a good place.

Comment: @Ken, it's more answer than a comment ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parent (containing) form's `OnShow` event:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Make sure grid's data is available by opening the
  // dataset first, and then call your AUtoSizeRows here.
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken, as always, another good answer ... I'm amazed you can provide all these helpful SO answers and still find the time to work!

Comment: :) Thanks. I wonder the same thing about David Heffernan and RRUZ, except I wonder not only when they work, but when they sleep. (Especially David - he's *always* here. <g>)

Comment: I'm pretty sure which  @DavidHeffernan is a robot :)